# Im getting this error while launching the app

Tags: android, crash, app-launcher

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.psa.mym.mycitroen, PID: 30782
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.psa.mym.MyMarqueApplication: java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter
specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter sslSocketFactory
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7227)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:287)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2166)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:255)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8212)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:632)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method
kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter sslSocketFactory
at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.sslSocketFactory(Unknown Source:7)
at com.psa.bouser.mym.impl.service.BOUserService.initialize(BOUserService.java:294)
at com.psa.mym.MyMarqueApplication.onCreate(MyMarqueApplication.java:166)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1192)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7222)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:287) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2166) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:255) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8212) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:632) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049)

im confused what should i do ?